# Jquery .submit() not working but submit button works fine

Tags: jquery, json, forms, model-view-controller

I have a .cshtml page containing a form as part of an MVC with Entity Framework.

The form submits correctly when I click the Submit button. If I use jquery to simulate clicking the submit button the form submits correctly. If I use AJAX to POST the form to the controller it works. But any variation I've tried of $('form').submit() returns the error:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

Obviously I can use one of the other methods to submit the form but I'm just curious why .submit() won't work.

This is my .cshtml page:

```
@model MVC.ViewModels.OrderView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Orders";
}
<div id="autosuggest_pricelist"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/orders_edit.js")"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Orders","PriceList", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Orders</legend>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderID)
    <div class="columns">
        <div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Supplier)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AssociateID,(SelectList) ViewBag.Suppliers)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssociateID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderStatus)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderStatus)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderStatus)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderNotes)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderNotes)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderNotes)
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
            <input class="inputlabel" style="width:15em;" disabled="disabled" value="Description" />
            <input class="inputlabel" disabled="disabled"; value="Quantity" />
            <input class="inputlabel" disabled="disabled"; value="Stock" />
            <input class="inputlabel" disabled="disabled"; value="Received" />
            <input class="inputlabel" disabled="disabled"; value="Invoiced" />
        </div>
        <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.OrderDetailView)
        </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Related Invoices","OrdersToInvoices","AuditTrail",new {id=Model.OrderID},new{})

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            <input type = "button" value = "Import" id="import"/>
            <input type="button" value="jquery submit" id="btnSubmit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "OrderList", new { count = 10 })
</div>
```

The follwing jquery returns the error:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    try {
        $('form').submit();
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err)
    }
})
```

whereas this submits the form:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/PriceList/Orders",
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                    }
                })
```

as does

```
$('#id_of_submit_button').click();
```

How do I see the JSon data being submitted by the form in each instance? Comparing the Json submitted by the submit button rather than .submit() might show me what was going on.

Comment: Can't you stick the result of `$('form').serialize()` into a variable and step through your Javascript to view the result?

Comment: That will show me what the ajax post is sending. How do I get what the .submit function is sending?

Comment: `$('form').submit();` shouldn't throw an error... what is the error?

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

Comment: that means .submit is NOT submitting the form, it's instead triggering a submit handler that is performing ajax. That submit handler is failing, and since you haven't provided it to us, we can't help you figure out why.

Comment: *"whereas this submits the form:"* No, that performs an ajax request.

Comment: Maybe I should just stick with my own ajax post then @KevinB and not worry about what's going on behind the scene?

Comment: Maybe so, though i would still be curious of what's going on if it were my application

Comment: My guess is whatever MVC framework you are using is writing some javascript for you. I **HATE** frameworks that do that.

Comment: Me too. Any way to find out?

Comment: hmm.... Let the error happen without the try/catch and look at it's stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to submit the form the default way, right? What's the difference between `$('form').submit()` and `$('form')[0].submit()`?

My understanding is:

```
$('form').submit(); //which is equivalent to
$('form').trigger( 'submit' );
```

Triggers the `submit` event thereby firing any defined `submit handlers`; **therefore the error may be caused by recursive submit event triggers**. On the other hand:

```
$('form')[0].submit(); //which is equivalent to
document.forms[0].submit(); //or
this.form.submit(); //where 'this' references a button in the form
```

Simply submits the form as when you click a submit button and there's not `return false` and 'event.preventDefault()` ... in short default form submission.

**This second form is what you want, I think.**

Comment: Is the correct answer. Funny I couldn't find it anywhere like the JQuery api - though I do understand that better now that I've read your answer. Thanks for your help.